# Generate table using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

[image: Updated Image]

```
    var months = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

            subGroup.push(now.getFullYear());

            for (var i = 1; i < 7; ++i) {
                var future = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1, i);
                if ((months[now.getMonth()]) == "January") {
                    subGroup.push((now.getFullYear()))
                }
                subGroup.push(months[now.getMonth()]);
            }
            subGroups.push(subGroup);
        });

        alert(subGroups);
        //debugger;
        var array = subGroups.toString().split(',');

        var arrayLength = array.length;
        var theTable = document.createElement('table');
        tr = document.createElement('tr');


        for (var i = 0, tr, td; i < arrayLength; i++) {

            td = document.createElement('td');
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));
            tr.appendChild(td);
            theTable.appendChild(tr);
        }

        document.getElementById('table').appendChild(theTable);`
```

I have a multi select dropdown and based on the number of  selection of dropdown I have to dynamically generate the table Like the following attached image . Future 6 Months will be displayed based on the current month. Please Can anybody help me !! [image: Dynamic generation of table based on dropdown selection]

Comment: please include all relevant code to OP.. include what you have done so far and which part are yiou having problems with

Comment: Hi guradio.,I am not able to generate textbox and entered value in textbox should be saved to database,. Please help me with sample code as i am new to jquery stuff.

Comment: What are the options in you dropdownlist, and how does selecting a value from it that relate to your code?

Comment: After selection of dropdown I need to forecast the data for next six months. So in order to forecast the 6 months data i need to generate the table with future months and textbox for entering the value. If i select 2 then 2 rows will be shown along with the textbox.

Comment: 2 rows of what? You have just said you only want textboxes for the next 6 months

Comment: Its a multiselect dropdown. If two values are selected then i have to forecast for two products and for different product different rows will be dynamically generated . I have added the screenshot.

Comment: And what are you binding the textboxes to? (what is the model and the controller method you will post the values to?

Comment: It will be key-Value pair. MonthID(YYYYMM: Format )-Textbox value(int) in a list. Through ajax call i have to send the data to the controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125147/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-s-sagar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a binding library such as Knockkout, when your drop down changes, build a view model with the month and empty value.

ex:
Include KnockoutJS in your page, download it from here http://knockoutjs.com/

build a model, ex:

```
var MonthViewModel = function(monthID, value) {
    this.monthID= ko.observable(monthID);
    this.monthValue= ko.observable(value);
};

var ViewModel = function(
var that = this;
that.months = ko.obserabaleArray();

that.addMonth = function(month){
  that.months.push(month);
}; 
){};

   var viewModel = new ViewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

Your HTML should be something like this:

```
<table id="months">
<tr data-bind="foreach:months">
 <td>
   <span data-bind="text:monthID"></span>
   <input type="text" data-bind="value:monthValue"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In your event that fires on changing the drop down selection, you should get the selected months, add it to the `viewModel` variable and the HTML will bind automatically